# Is there a command for video bitrate in html5?

Tags: html, video-streaming, bitrate

I am using "document.querySelector('video').playbackRate=1" as a console input in the edge browser, for setting the playbackspeed on the fly. Is there a similar command to use for customizing the bitrate of that video stream?

Answer (score 1):

No. The bitrate of a video is a result of how source video was encoded. In order to change bitrate, you have to either have multiple source videos that are each encoded at a different bitrate (like Youtube does it) or have the ability to change the encoding on the fly in response to network congestion (like a live stream).

Comment: So if I have a source like youtube or netflix or any other stream that provides a sortment of different bitrates, how can I chose one using a console command?

Comment: @soccerjk You have to change the source the HTML5 video element is pulling from and possibly the position in the video after you change sources. There is no simply console command to do this for you.